# Cannot start ps4

Tags: ps4

Me and my mum were moving around the furniture in my room which meant both tv and ps4, we accidentally unplugged the PlayStation without turning it off properly (as in not rest mode) and now when I try to use it it comes up with the message 
"Cannot start the ps4
 Connect the dual shock 4 using the usb cable and then press the ps button"
The issue is when I do what it says nothing happens, the controller just flashes white then goes back to the normal orange flash that comes up when it is plugged in

Comment: Plug the other controller.

Comment: Or stick a needle in the back of the controller into the reset button.